# Winforms GDI leak despite using static font or disposal of font?

Tags: .net, winforms, fonts, gdi, resource-leak

I have a static Font object in a Winforms Application. It's dynamically creating and destroying controls like edit boxes etc. On some the Font property is assigned from a static (singleton) Font object. Despite the fact that there is only one font object, every time(!) a control is destroyed and recreated using the same(!) font object, the GDI Object count increases by one. GDIView shows that this is a font object. When not assigning the Font property to the new control there is no GDI Object increase.

I also tried to dynamically recreate the Font object every time a control is created and disposing it when the control is disposed, but it does not make a difference.

Is this a bug in Winforms (.NET 4.5.2, VS2015, also tried .NET 3.5 ) or do I miss something? There are many questions here regarding GDI resource leaks but none answered my question.

Here a small Winforms TestApp with only a single button on it initially to demonstrate the problem:

```
    private const string Todelete = "todelete";

#if !DYNAMIC_FONT
    static readonly Font Font = new Font("Arial", 11, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);  
#endif
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Controls.Find(Todelete, false).FirstOrDefault()?.Dispose();

        var ctrl = new TextBox();
#if !DYNAMIC_FONT
        ctrl.Font = Font;//leaks GDI handle every time!
#else
        ctrl.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, GraphicsUnit.Pixel); 
        // does not help:
        ctrl.Disposed += (sender2, args) => ((Control)sender2).Font.Dispose();
#endif
        ctrl.Name = Todelete;
        Controls.Add(ctrl);
    }
```

btw. there are no USER Object leaks, so the control is deleted properly, but both variants leak a GDI Object every time the button is pressed. Not assigning the Font property resolves it, but how do I assign a Font without leak?

Comment: comboBox.Name is a bug in your test program, should be ctrl.Name.  Winforms "leaks" font objects by design.  Unlike all the other drawing objects, they are very expensive to create so it caches them.  A cache is not a memory leak.  A true memory leak causes unbounded memory/handle consumption, the kind that makes a program crash.  Get confidence by running the code 10,000 times, you'll see the GDI object counter bounce up and down.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, before reaching 400-500 control creations the GDI Object count drops back. It's surprises me that the very same font object is instantiated so many times as GDI Object internally. When there is a cache, why it is not reusing the GDI Object?

Comment: @HansPassant this is a great answer, you should post it as one.

Comment: Some day I'll figure out exactly how the font cache works.  It is very obscure, not today.